# On Dahsboard, can't delete videos individually?

Tags: zalenium

On Dashboard, Can’t delete individual videos. Either Reset or Cleanup dashboard options available. Can we have a selection checkbox to delete selected videos from dashboard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that feature is not supported yet.